# How to discover which backing beans are referenced in a given web page in a JSF 2.1 application?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

My config: JSF 2.1/Java 7

What I need is to register an interceptor that allows me to detect which backing beans are being referenced in any EL expressions existing in a web page that is about to be processed.

I don't want interfere in the page rendering process or in any JSF phase, just to be able to list all the backing beans that will have to exist in order to produce the final html page.

TIA

Comment: Why do you need this runtime?

Comment: I'm building a new scope type and have to control the lifecycle of the backing beans annotated with this new scope type. Part of the process of deciding if a given bean is to be destroyed or not depends on this.

Comment: But then you can also look at which beans were used when rendering the page (so have a list after rendering instead of one upfront). A 'dummy' EL resolver could help with this. One that does not resolve the beans but keeps track of which ones are requested to be resolved. And then at the end destroy the ones that were previously resolved but not in this request. Personally I'd say that upgrading to JSF 2.2 is easier and more future proof.

Comment: Totally agree about JSF 2.2, but I'm having all this work because that path is out of my reach. Regarding your suggestion, It does not fit my needs because sometimes the next view will referente a different backing bean that belongs to the same, lets say, Bean family. Those anotations will create bean families and those beans must be kept alive while the user navigates among them. In the moment a navigation stops referencing all those beans, then all members of the Bean family must die.

Comment: _"because that path is out of my reach. "_ I can help you persuade the ones blocking this... simple approach: make it a security issue.

Comment: Thank you, I'll make that part of my strategy, but at this very moment, considering my time restrictions and all the legacy I have to keep working, my question continues.